# Is it correct to say products line or product line?

Tags: grammar

If a company has several products, is that a products line or a product line?

Answer (score -1):

A *product line* is a sub-category of all the products which a business produces/sells - or the merchandise on display in a shop or catalogue.

Each *product line* will contain a number of products.

Notwithstanding that, in my experience, the usual nomenclature is ***product line*** i.e. singular.

Comment: Not my downvote, but in any case the question is about *products* vs *product*, not *line* vs *lines*.